# Работает ли mod_rewrite c ajax запросами?

Tags: .htaccess, ajax, mod_rewrite

Есть такое правило:

```
RewriteRule ^.*$ router.php
```

Я делаю такой ajax запрос:

```
xmlHttp.open("POST", "phpscripts/try_ajax.php", true);
xmlHttp.send(params);
```

Он благополучно игнорирует правило RewriteRule, успешно находит try_ajax.php (в папочке phpscripts) и выполняет его. Меня это полностью устраивает, но возникает вопрос, нормально ли это? Я думал что mod_rewrite перелопачивает все ссылки. Я ошибался?

Comment: Если это происходит с аякс, то тоже самое будет происходить, если в браузере вбить этот адрес.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В yii, например, использутся такое правило и всё работает. А разницы ajax запрос или нет - нет, признак ajax всего лишь заголовок.

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)\?*$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Объясните, пожалуйста, что значат -f и -d? в гугле непонятно написано.

Comment: пропустить запрос если это файл или папка реально существуют

Comment: ну вроде со всем раобрался, спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Если вы отправите запрос на не существующий файл. тогда он уйдет в router.php
Аджакс тут не причем. Обычный запрос будет вести себя точно так же.

ps с jquery слать ajax запросы удобнее